# How can I store user id in session for per request in asp net core web api project?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, request, asp.net-core-webapi

I have middleware that get jwt from header and parse it:

```
     public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string tokenString = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenString))
        {
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
        var jwtEncodedString = tokenString.Substring(7);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtEncodedString: jwtEncodedString);
        string userId = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
        string userName = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "preferred_username").Value;
        string name = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "given_name").Value;
        string surname = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "family_name").Value;
        var roles = token.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "user_roles").ToList();
        var lastRole = "";
        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            lastRole = role.Value;
        }
        httpContext.Session.SetString("userId", userId);
        httpContext.Session.SetString("userName", userName);
        httpContext.Session.SetString("name", name);
        httpContext.Session.SetString("surname", surname);
        httpContext.Session.SetString("role", lastRole);
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

In Configure method of startup I add middleware: app.UseSession().UseCustomMiddleware();
When request comes middleware parse jwt, but in another request session data is enabled yet. I want to make session per request sensitive. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you want to set the session data which came from the jwt token initially and each request could get the session?

Comment: Now, I get jwt from request header in custom middleware, and set jwt data(name, role and so on) to session, but I want this session is enabled for per request, next request can not get session data before setting session